# Switch themes in Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a fully functional site with Symfony and Twig.

Now I want to do this: put two or more themes in `src/AppBundle/Resources/views` folder, like `theme1` and `theme2`, under two different directories: `theme1` and `theme2` so that I can somehow change the theme of my site quickly.

I put the template reference in my TWIG template from:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:default:index.html.twig'...
```

to something like:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:theme1:default:index.html.twig'...
```

But it does not work: can't find the template.

Any help on this?

Comment: I think that after two colons you need to use slashes: `AppBundle:theme1:default/index.html.twig`, and deeper: `AppBundle:theme1:default/front/panel/advert.html.twig` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:theme1:default:index.html.twig'...
```

You should use this:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:theme1/default:index.html.twig'...
```

Or this:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:theme1:default/index.html.twig'...
```

Comment: To provide some more context: The `BundleName:ActionName:TemplateName` notation is parsed in Symfony by a special [TemplateNameParser](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/TemplateNameParser.php#L58) which only handles template names containing exactly two colons. Everything else is handled as usual which means that the template would not be found.

Comment: Yes, that is the way. Thanks.

Comment: In any case, the modern and recommended way to refer to templates is `return $this->render('@App/theme1/default/index.html.twig'...`. As you can see, with this notation you'll never have any trouble no matter how many folders you create.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in my Symfony project, depending which domain I view my site from will flick templates. You might have a different use case, but here is an example of how I achieved my result.

Add the following function to **src/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php**

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('bundle_name');

    $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('sites')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('domain')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->validate()->ifNull()->thenInValid("Domain name must be set")->end()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('template_directory')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->validate()->ifNull()->thenInValid("Template Directory must be set")->end()->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
    ;

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

*Replace bundle_name with your name of choice.*

Add the following to **app/config/parameters.yml**

```
bundle_name:
    sites:
        site1:
            domain: first-domain.tld
            template_directory: theme1
        site2:
            domain: second-domain.tld
            template_directory: theme2
```

*You can add as many sites as you want - providing you have the themes setup*

Create an event listener **src/YourBundle/EventListener/TemplateListener.php**

```
<?php

    namespace YourBundle\EventListener;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

    class TemplateListener
    {

        /** @var \Twig_Environment */
        private $twig;

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        private $hostsConfig;

        public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, $hostsConfig) {
            $this->twig = $twig;
            $this->hostsConfig = $hostsConfig;
        }

        public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
            $currentHost = $event->getRequest()->getHost();

            if(isset($this->hostsConfig[$currentHost])) {
                $templateDirectory = $this->hostsConfig[$currentHost]['template_directory'];    
            } else {
                $templateDirectory = 'theme1';
            }

            $this->twig->getLoader()->prependPath(dirname(__DIR__) . '/../YourBundle/Resources/views/' . $this->hostsConfig[$currentHost]['template_directory']);
        }
    }
```

By default it will render 'theme1' but if it exists in the **parameters.yml** then it will match the template directory and render views from that directory.

Update **src/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php**

```
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        //...

        $sites = array();

        //Re arrange the sites configuration to be easily accessed by domain as index
        foreach ($config['sites'] as $siteConfig) {
            $sites[$siteConfig['domain']]['template_directory'] = $siteConfig['template_directory'];
        }

        $container->setParameter('hosts.config', $sites);

        //...
    }
```

You'll need to update all your controllers (Or whatever you use to render your views).

Instead of using the normal method of **Class:Bundle:Folder** you just need to use a relative path as if you were in **views/theme1(or)theme2/**

```
return $this->render(
    'default/index.html.twig',
    array(
        ...
    )
)
```

This will check
    **src/YourBundle/Resources/views/theme1/default/index.html.twig**

or
    **src/YourBundle/Resources/views/theme2/default/index.html.twig**

depending what domain you accessing.

[The original tutorial that I followed was here.](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/symofny2-twig-multiple-domains-templating/)